# Wrong number of arguments issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following jQuery sortable code:

```
$( ".list" ).sortable({
update: function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/books/sort',
    type: 'post',
    items: 'li',
    data: $('.list').sortable('serialize'),
    dataType: 'script',
    complete: function(request){
      alert("jjjj");
    }
  });
}
});
```

and a sort action in my controller like:

```
def sort
   params[:book].each_with_index do |id, index|
     Book.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
   end
   render nothing: true
end
```

but I get the error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
   app/controllers/books_controller.rb:28:in `block in sort'
```

Comment: `Book.update_all({position: (index+1), id: id})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as below

```
Book.where(id: id).
  update_all(position: index+1)
```

If you read the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), it says explicitly :-

> Parameters :
>
> updates - A string, array, or hash representing the SET part of an SQL statement.

Comment: I now get the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique: UPDATE "books" SET "position" = 1, "id" = 34)`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this `id: id` ? Why are you updating the `id`, that caused the second issue.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know, I was following: http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised

Comment: Sorry, I can't see as I didn't subscribed it. But your first question is now solved. To solve the second one need more context.

Comment: I see now, because without it, it updates like `UPDATE "books" SET "position" = 1`, I need it to associate each id with its position.

Comment: So basically, params[:book] has a list of ids: `{"book"=>["34", "33", "35", "36"]}`, so I need to update each id with its position.

Comment: @Muhambi Then do `params[:book].each_with_index { |id, index| Book.find(id).update(index+1) }`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this, but got `ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):`

Comment: Sorry it should be `Book.find(id).update(position: index+1)` I forgot to mention the key.

Comment: thanks I actually tried `Book.find(id).update_attribute(:position, index+1)` and that worked as well, thanks for your help!

Comment: Someone should post this in the screencast comments section. Excellent work!

Answer (score 5):

If someone lands here wondering the same thing, the reason why you get "Wrong number of arguments" it's cause there was a change in Rails (I believe it was on 4.0) that *moved* the section where you specify the condition.

So, for this to work, you'd have to use something like this:

```
def sort
   params[:book].each_with_index do |id, index|
     Book.where(id: id).update_all({position: index+1})
   end
   render nothing: true
end
```

And everything else will work as expected.